# Geopandas .merge() produces strange results

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have been trying to merge two geopandas dataframes based on a column and am getting some really weird results. To test this point I made two simple dataframes, and merged them:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'City': ['Buenos Aires', 'Brasilia', 'Santiago', 'Bogota', 'Caracas'],
     'Country': ['Argentina', 'Brazil', 'Chile', 'Colombia', 'Venezuela'],
     'Latitude': [-34.58, -15.78, -33.45, 4.60, 10.48],
     'Longitude': [-58.66, -47.91, -70.66, -74.08, -66.86]})

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Capital': ['Buenos Aires', 'Brasilia', 'Santiago', 'Bogota', 
     'Caracas'],
     'Abbreviation': ['ARG', 'BRA', 'CHI', 'COL', 'VZL']})

combined_df = gdf.merge(df2, left_on='City', right_on='Capital')

print(combined_df)
```

When I print the results, I get what I expected:

```
           City    Country  ...       Capital  Abbreviation
0  Buenos Aires  Argentina  ...  Buenos Aires           ARG
1      Brasilia     Brazil  ...      Brasilia           BRA
2      Santiago      Chile  ...      Santiago           CHI
3        Bogota   Colombia  ...        Bogota           COL
4       Caracas  Venezuela  ...       Caracas           VZL
```

The two datasets are merged based on their common column, which is the 'city' column and the 'capital' column.

I have some other data I am working with. [Here is a link to it](https://github.com/epurpur/Geopandas-Merge-Dataframes/tree/master)

Both of the files are geopackages I've read in as geodataframes. Dataframe 1 has 16166 rows. Dataframe 2 has 15511 rows. They have a common ID column, 'ALTPARNO' AND 'altparno'. Here is the code I've tried to use to read them in and merge them:

```
import geopandas as gpd

dataframe1 = gpd.read_file(filepath, layer='allkeepers_2019')
dataframe2 = gpd.read_file(filepath, layer='keepers_2019')

results = dataframe1.merge(dataframe2, left_on='altparno', right_on='ALTPARNO')
```

When I look at my results, I have a dataframe with over 4 million rows (should be around 15,000).

What is going on?

Comment: Are their multiple records for the same ID? That would cause a join two have multiple records per value. try `dataframe1['altparno'].value_counts()` and  `dataframe2['ALTPARNO'].value_counts()` . If you have any records with multiples, that is your issue

Comment: It appears there are not multiple records with the same ID. I am not really sure what was happening but I created a false ID number and was able to join on the newly created column

Comment: that is extremely strange. What happens when you start playing with the `validate` argument in [`pd.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) ? Try 1:1, 1:m, etc. and see if there are any clues there